# How to use page index changing in grid view filtered data using drop down list in c#

Tags: c#

I have one grid view and it displays filtered data. When i select drop down it displays data (10 records limit in in grid view) but for remaining records in grid view when i click on 2 page it refresh the page and filtered data is not display

Comment: Please post your problematic code and what doesn't work in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
                AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="OnSorting" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"
                PageSize="10">
                <Columns>    
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```